# Paypal Mobile SDK cannot proceed payment, received unknown error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I wonder if anyone can help me with this problem. I receive this error from my iOS SDK, for 2 attempted requests:

```
2015-01-22 16:14:32.238 Page Advisor Consumer[6442:607] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNKNOWN_ERROR - System error (UNKNOWN_ERROR). Please try again later. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: be3d18e185478 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.8.2]
2015-01-22 16:15:06.557 Page Advisor Consumer[6442:607] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNKNOWN_ERROR - System error (UNKNOWN_ERROR). Please try again later. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: 52795d8d95006 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.8.2]
```

I wonder what cause this error. Because when I use direct payment REST API there seems to be no problem at all. I already use US Account. Please tell me if i need to provide anymore details. Thank you guys!

UPDATE::!!
I have done further testing, turns out that Mobile SDK somehow cannot create transaction in SGD if connected to a US account, while REST API allows it. Turns out the SDK needs Singapore Account in order to proceed.

The problem is Singapore Account cannot use the newest SDK. Any solution for this? I really desperately need the newest SDK to work with SGD, because the current REST API allows it.

Thanks

Comment: This is what i get when i use sandbox

2015-01-22 16:47:40.532 Page Advisor Consumer[6583:607] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNKNOWN_ERROR - System error (UNKNOWN_ERROR). Please try again later. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: ff76c5ad7af96 [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.8.2]

Comment: I recommend you call PayPal. Sounds like they may have an issue (bug) they need to fix on their side, or they may be able to tell you if that is a known limitation of the SDK.... in which case they should be giving you a real error like "currency not supported", so either way they have a bug which they should fix :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the debug IDs you provided (both Live and Sandbox) and they were all failing for the same reason: unsupported currency for direct credit card transactions.

SGD is not a supported currency for Direct Credit cards with the REST APIs. A list of supported direct credit card currencies can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments). SGD *is* a supported currency for PayPal payments with the REST APIs. Since the mSDK sits on top of the REST APIs, the supported currency list for REST and mSDK are one and the same.

As for the error message itself, I will put in a request with the appropriate folks to see if we can display something a bit more informative.

Comment: IF it is so...do you have tutorials or reference as of how we can implement Credit Card Payment in mobile Apps? Is MEC the only way? I actually prefer not to because it is in web view....
Thanks

Comment: PayPal is always looking to update supported currencies so it's possible that you may be able to use mSDK for SGD in the future, however if you don't want to use MEC, you can check with Braintree.  I'm not familiar with all the currencies that they may/may not offer.